# Not able to see value option in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to create a stacked column chart in Power BI desktop. Once I drag the stacked column chart from the visualization, it only shows options for X-Axis, Y-Axis, Legend, Small multiples, Tooltips.

But the values seems to be missing from the above list.

[image]

Any pointers will help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`Y-Axis` is the new `Value` field.